# Apk decompile error: d2j-dex2jar command not found

Tags: apk, dex2jar

I try to get source code from an .apk

I followed the steps from right here 
[Is there a way to get the source code from an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file) but on Step 2.4 when I wrote on my cmd `dex2jar path> d2j-dex2jar classes.dex` I get

"***'d2j-dex2jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch files.***"

any solutions ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `dex2jar classes.dex` instead of `d2j-dex2jar classes.dex`
And please check which version of **dex2jar** is with you.
if it is *dex2jar-2.x*  jar file then , please try to download *dex2jar-0.0.9.15* jar file.

Comment: I checked so many answers. This was the only one that worked for me.

Comment: Good to hear that :) happy coding!

Comment: Then what is the purpose of upgraded version?

Answer (score 27):

for dex2jar 2.0 version please follow below steps to generate jar

1. download dex2jar (https://sourceforge.net/projects/dex2jar/files/)
2. extract folder
3. goto folder in command prompt
4. chmod u+x d2j_invoke.sh
5. chmod u+x d2j-dex2jar.sh
6. put desired apk to decompile in dex2jar folder
7. sh d2j-dex2jar.sh -f -o output_jar.jar my_app.apk
8. This will generate output_jar.jar in same folder

Answer (score 5):

Add permission with: chmod +x d2j-dex2jar.sh
Then run it with: ./d2j-dex2jar.sh app.apk

Comment: ./d2j-dex2jar.sh: line 36: ./d2j_invoke.sh: Permission denied

Comment: "chmod +x d2j_invoke.sh" add permission for this file also

Answer (score 1):

place all the apk file, coverted zip, apktool, apktool install, dex2jar, jd-gui folders under a single folder...
open command prompt(admin)..
then goto the  directory of your newly created folder..
then type... d2j-dex2jar classes.dex , press enter...
thats it ur problem is solved...cheezzz

no need to add any xtra permissions...it workwed for me..it'll work for you too...

Answer (score 1):

If you have downloaded the **d2j-dex2jar-2.x** then **it would not contain the d2j-dex2jar.sh file**

so, try to download the **dex2jar-0.0.9.15** from the link
[dex2jar-0.0.9.15](http://auto-download.com/download/get/Oh_otXfB/dex2jar-0_0_9_15_zip.html)

**Finally extract this zip file and you will find the d2j-dex2jar.sh file**.

Hopefully this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Just goto the folder where you put your classes.dex file then just run the command in command prompt
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X3aP.png

-Make sure you have downloaded the dex2jar latest version which is dex2jar-2.0.
download it with this link

https://sourceforge.net/projects/dex2jar/

-It will then make your classes.dex file to executable jar 'classes-dex2jar.jar'

Answer (score 0):

you must use dex2jar-0.0.9.15 to decompile apk older version dos'nt work correctly because missing some files via extension bat