# There is no file named d2j-dex2jar.sh in the dex2jar when i unzipped it

Tags: java, android

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and want to extract a apk, I have downloaded dex2jar and extracted it and run the command ./d2j-dex2jar classes.dex but the terminal returns "No such file or directory"

This is true as there is no such file or directory to be executed.

I did a through research on the matter and everywhere it was mentioned the same thing unzip dex2jar and run the above mentioned command.

What is that I am missing that i am unable to convert .dex file to .jar file.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file?noredirect=1&lq=1) first, but got the same problem as you.

Then I found [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29744010/apk-decompile-error-d2j-dex2jar-command-not-found) and it solved my problem. Just download the dex2jar-0.0.9.15.jar it provided. You will be able to find d2j-dex2jar.sh in the extracted folder! Hope this would be helpful.